How to add a OpenTopoMap legend
I'm a beginner when it comes to using GIS in general and QGIS  in particular.
I use xyz OpenTopoMap as my basemap and want to display an appropriate legend in my layout, but don't understand the basics behind all this. Even reading manuals doesn't seem to much of a help.
Can you shed some light on this matter?

Raster tile servers don't serve legends, but you could build your own manually using symbols from here or here.

Make your own legend image using symbols from here or here using  an image editor like Photoshop, GIMP, Inkscape or Paint. Or take a screenshot of an existing OpenTopoMap legend.
Then when in Map view, open the OpenTopoMap layer "Properties", select the Legend entry and load the legend image you created as a "Legend placeholder image":


Here is an example using a screenshot from the symbols here though I don't recommend using this one without some editing as it's a bit too spaced out:

In the print layout view, you can then use the add legend tool and the OpenTopoMap legend you just added will be displayed.

That 's a nice solution; thanks for the clear explanation!

In your Print Layout, the adding a Legend tool is located on the toolbar along the left side. That is the basic way to add a legend to any map you would be working with in QGIS.
However, your legend will likely be empty due to the data from OpenTopoMap being a raster.
Let me know some more details about what you are trying to display and I'll try to help more.


Thanks for answering!
Okay, I couldn't find any hint in the QGIS manuals on how to create a legend from scratch.
I understand that I need to create layers for that, but what kind and how? How for example do I add a legend entry for different kind of roads visible on a map. How to add the icon and the text for it?
Adding the legend and configuring it from the layout is not my issue that is pretty straightforward. My issue is more on how to create a legend entry manually.
Hope that makes my point clear enough!
Regards, Gerard
